# Expecting a type supporting the operator '-' but given a function type

Tags: f#

Can anyone clarify why I got this message (see commented two lines below), and maybe point to the correct specification of user defined binary operators.
Why do I have to define operator (.-->.) outside the type definition and and not  (.>>=.)?

```
type ListA<'T> = NIL | Cons of 'T * ListA<'T> with
        static member cat (a:ListA<'T>) (b:ListA<'T>) :ListA<'T>=
            match a with
                | NIL -> b
                | Cons (a, tail) -> Cons (a, (ListA<'T>.cat tail b))
        static member join (a:ListA<ListA<'T>>)  =
            match a with
                | NIL -> NIL
                | Cons (a, b) -> ListA<'T>.cat a (ListA<'T>.join b)

        static member fmap (fn: 'T -> 'U) (a:ListA<'T>)  =
                 match a with
                    | NIL -> NIL
                    | Cons (a, tail) -> Cons ((fn a), (ListA<'T>.fmap fn tail))
        
        static member inline (.>>=.)(ma:ListA<'T> , k:'T -> ListA<'U>) =  ListA<'T>.fmap k ma |> ListA<_>.join

        static member inline (.<<<.)(mbc:'B -> ListA<'C> , mab:'T -> ListA<'B>) = (fun x -> (mab x) .>>=. mbc)
        static member inline (.>>>.)(mab:'T -> ListA<'B> , mbc:'B -> ListA<'C>) = (fun x -> (mab x) .>>=. mbc)
        
        static member join2 (a:ListA<_>)  =  a .>>=. id
    
    
    let (.-->.)(mab:'T -> ListA<'B>) (mbc:'B -> ListA<'C>) = (fun x -> (mab x) .>>=. mbc)
    let (.<--.)(mab:'B -> ListA<'C>) (mbc:'T -> ListA<'B>) = (fun x -> (mbc x) .>>=. mab)
    
    let f  = fun x ->  Cons (x, Cons ((x + 1), NIL))    
    let g  = fun x ->  Cons (x * 2, NIL)
    // NOT Compiling: let fgA = fun x -> (f .<<<. g) 
    // NOT Compiling: let fgB = fun x -> (f .>>>. g) 
    let fg = fun x -> (f x) .>>=. g
    let fg1 = (f .-->. g .-->. g)
    let fg2 = (f .<--. g .-->. f)
    printfn "%A" (fg1 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Such are the rules of operator lookup. First (1) the compiler tries to see if the operator is defined as a method on one of the operands' types, and then (2) it tries to look in the current lexical context (i.e. the current module and any `open`ed modules).

*(incidentally, rule (1) is common for all .NET, while rule (2) is F# only)*

`.>>=.` works, because it's defined on the type of its first argument `(f x)`, so rule (1) applies.

`.-->.` works because it's defined in the current context, so rule (2) applies.

But in the expression `f .>>>. g` the type of both arguments is a function `'a -> ListA<'a>`, and this type doesn't have operator `.>>>.` defined as a method, and no operator `.>>>.` is defined in the current context, so neither rule (1) nor rule (2) applies, and the compiler has no idea where to look up this operator.

Comment: Excellent answer. Very helpful

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider "accepting" it. You can do this by clicking the pale grey checkmark to the left is the answer.